# How to change configuration in memory

Tags: asp.net, configuration

Im wondering if this is possible. I would really like to ship my application with no configuration file (stop users fiddling with it). Is it possible to set all the configuration in memory in say the global.asax (application_start) event? For example I dont want users messing directly with the connection string I want them to be able to modify it in the gui only. And i dont want to have to write to the config file as there may be security issues....

Comment: You could use a database to store settings (not particularly uncommon) and store the connection string for the given database in the app settings - L2S does this by default; connects with the connection used in the DBML Designer unless you initialise the context with a conenction string or similar.

Answer (score 0):

you could still use the file system and have the files encrypted. In this way only you can modify or from the app, but no one can really modify the configurations directly from the file. Also you could encrypt Configuration Sections: [Check this Microsoft Link out](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/zhhddkxy.aspx).

Good luck!